# Deserializing IEnumerable<T<U>> using JSon.NET

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have been able to serialize a JSON array as seen below:

```
[
  {
    "AssociatedOrders": [
      {
        "ID": {
          "Value": 0
        },
        "TransactionReferences": {
          "Authorization": ""
        },
        "ShipToName": ""
      }
    ],
    "BillToCustomer": {
      "Value": "0"
    },
    "ID": {
      "Value": 0
    },
    "Lines": [
      {
        "Amount": 0,
        "Description": "",
        "OrderID": {
          "Value": 0
        }
      }
    ],
    "PayerName": "",
    "PaymentDate": "",
    "PaymentMethod": "",
    "PaymentReferenceNumber": ""
  },
  {
    "AssociatedOrders": [
      {
        "ID": {
          "Value": 0
        },
        "TransactionReferences": {
          "Authorization": ""
        },
        "ShipToName": ""
      }
    ],
    "BillToCustomer": {
      "Value": "0"
    },
    "ID": {
      "Value": 0
    },
    "Lines": [
      {
        "Amount": 0,
        "Description": "",
        "OrderID": {
          "Value": ""
        }
      }
    ],
    "PayerName": "",
    "PaymentDate": "",
    "PaymentMethod": "",
    "PaymentReferenceNumber": ""
  }
 ]
```

The WebAPI call returns IEnumerable>but when I try to deserialize with

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<SomeClass<SomeOtherClass>>>(data, JsonSerializerSettings);
```

where data is the returned json string and json serializer settings are set to

```
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.None,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        };
```

the request crashes with the following error:

```
Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: Float.
```

From what I've read this array is a JsonArray (`JArray`). But how would I be able to loop over this JArray and ensure that the values are appropriately mapped to the `SomeClass<SomeOtherClass>` construct?

How would I properly read in the `JArray` so that the object properties are mapped?

**Solved:**

Turns out it was actually an out-dated reference issue. My API that returns the JSON was using a newer version of a package than the client. So the client was thinking the return type was of type `NodaMoney.Money` while in the updated package it was `decimal`. All I did was update the client package and everything worked as normal. Thought I would undelete the post so people would not make the same mistake I did. Wasted so much time on this, oh well, lesson learned.

Comment: Should it be "Deserializing IEnumerable<T<U>> using JSon.NET"?

Comment: Yes, it should be deserializing to the same contruct it was serialized to. It is serialized to IEnumerable<Receipt<ID>> and deserialized to the same.

Comment: can you please post your class definitions?

Comment: Did you try uploading your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/, then deserializing it as a `List<RootObject>` ?

Comment: You need to change `PaymentDate` to be nullable: `public DateTime? PaymentDate;`.  That's because, in your JSON, it is an empty string.  But that shouldn't cause the precise exception you are seeing.  Are you sure there isn't some `JsonConverter` for your `ID` classes you aren't telling us about?  Can you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?